# Strange prb wiith NSUrlRequest

Tags: objective-c, session, nsurlrequest, ios8.1

I try to send a large string 30k with NSURLRequest via NSSession downloadTaskWithRequest but all datas are not sent ?!

```
-(NSURLRequest*) GetMySQLCommand
{
    NSString *StringToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat: POST_SEND_SQL, _myHashIdstr, _mySQLType, _mySQLStringCommand, _mySQLProcReturn, _myStrId];

    NSLog(@"-----> Post Data = %@", StringToSend);

    NSData *postData = [StringToSend dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", (unsigned long long)[postData length]];

    NSLog(@"-----> Post Data to send = %@", postLength);

    _myRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [_myRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [_myRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_myIpAdress0]];
    [_myRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [_myRequest setValue:@"text/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [_myRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    return _myRequest;
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that makes the request? Why `downloadTaskWithRequest`? Have you looked at the request with a network analyzer such as Charles proxy?

Comment: Yes i used network analyzer and not all data sent

Comment: If i sent small data it's ok ???

Comment: Some of the data was sent? What was missing?NSLog() `postData` and compare that to what the analyzers shows as sent. What is the return code?

Comment: In fact is json text and in my HTTP server i use use serialize and as don't have all datas this is my error

Comment: If i sent small data it's ok ???

Comment: And my postLength is correct !